# How to install bootstrap in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

How to install Bootstrap in new angular 8
I tried many times, and it did not work
I used this article [getting-started](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

Comment: Where exactly it didnot work ? hopefully you did all that is mentioned [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started#installation)

Comment: ng-bootstrap NOT require install Bootstrap. Simple download the bootstrap.min.css, save in a folder (I like put it in the same folder where you has your file `styles.css`) of your app -NOT in assets folder- and change the file `angular.json`. In the "tag" `styles`add the bootstrap.min.css so this becomes like `"styles": ["src/bootstrap.min.css","src/styles.css"],`

Comment: Thx now it is working ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this 
Install bootstrap package

```
npm i bootstrap
```

style.css

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

*So first you'll need to install the library from npm using the following command:*

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

*Once you finish the installation you'll need to import the main module.*

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

*Next you'll need to add the module you imported in your app root module*

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [/*...*/],
  imports: [/*...*/, NgbModule.forRoot()],
  /*...*/
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

*Please note that ng-bootstrap requires the Bootstrap 4 CSS file to be present.*

You can add it in the styles array of the angular.json file like that:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
```